# How to get Id by interaction of element which is part of List<Element> in .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, arraylist

I have a list of elements which are displayed on a page by a for-loop. I want to get data of the selected element into an asp.net view. How can I realize that?

This is the action of the controller which returns a List of elements:

```
public ActionResult MainContent()
{
    SiteContext db = new SiteContext();

    db.SaveChanges();
    var model = db.Posts.ToList();
    return PartialView("MainContent", model);
}
```

Partial view of MainContent:

```
@model IEnumerable<LayersDAL.Entity.Post>

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    <ul>
        <li>
            //Here is I'm trying to send element Id of current loop iteration to CurrentPost but something goes wrong :(
            <a class="post-ref" href="@Url.Action("CurrentPost", "Notes", new { Model.ToList()[i].PostId })">
                <h2>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.ToList()[i].Title)</h2>
                <p>

                </p>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
}
```

CurrentPost action:

```
    public ActionResult CurrentPost(int? id)
    {
        SiteContext db = new SiteContext();
        var post = db.Posts.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PostId == id);
        return PartialView(post);
    }
```

Partial view of CurrentPost:

```
<div class="modal-post">

        <div class="modal-post-divs">

            <span class="close">&times;</span>
        </div>
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div>
            <label>@Model.Title</label>
        </div>

</div>
```

[List of elements in Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCJZf.png)

[Error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhK8K.png)

So, what can I do? :)

UPD:

Thanks guys, I resolved that problem :)

Comment: first check, that your modal containing data or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your link code to the following:

```
            <a class="post-ref" href="@Url.Action("CurrentPost", "Notes", new { id =  Model[i].PostId })">
            <h2>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i].Title)</h2>
            <p>

            </p>
        </a>
```

You've already converted it to a List in your controller, so you don't need to call ToList() on the model in the View (and especially not inside a for loop!). Also make sure that you name the parameter that you're passing to the CurrentPost() method.
In the CurrentPost() method itself you should double check that the id parameter is valid and not null as follows:

```
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Post post = db.Posts.Find(id);
        if (post == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

FirstOrDefault() returns null if no item found so your model will be null.

```
 public ActionResult CurrentPost(int? id)
 {
      SiteContext db = new SiteContext();
      var post = db.Posts.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PostId == id);
      return PartialView(post);
 }
```

you can check it on your view to avoid erros.

```
@if(Model != null)
{
  // your code.
}
else
{
<p>No item found </p>
}
```

Comment: Good work :) appreciated can we create a generic method for checking model null or not?